# C# Comparing user input with data from external file C#

Tags: c#, console, console-application

Sorry if the post is duplicated, but I couldn't find any case like mine that is posted here or somewhere else.

I am working on a C# console application that should save the user input and then read it again "Something like a simple sign up and login application".

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Reader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filepath = @"C:\myProgramingFiles\password.txt";

            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filepath);

            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Write your username:");
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Write your password:");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(userInput);
            Console.WriteLine(password);

            while(line != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(userInput == line);
                Console.WriteLine(password == line);
                if (userInput == line)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your username is: " + line);
                }
                if(password == line)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your password is: " + line);
                }
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code that reads the data from password.txt, and everything works fine, but when I do the if-else it's first checks if both user inputs are the same as the username, and then it loops again and checks if both user inputs are like the password. Sorry if I couldn't make it clear, you can run this code if you want and mock up the password.txt, and check it.

It is actually a logical and expected result, but the thing is that I don't know how else I should do it. Can you please help me?

**I have tried a lot of things that didn't work, and this was my last try, so I know that it is not the best code, but it explains the problem**

Comment: Ideally you would want your password to be assigned to a username. Your current approach doesn't do this. As a solution treat the username and password as a pair in your external file. If you want simple then make it so that each username in that file is followed by a password on the next line. Then when you use your loop, check for the existence of a matching username. If found, then, compare the passwords.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here. I can't find a question in your post. What is the input and expected output you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry I found it har to explain. I have two different texts in a file called password.txt 
User1
Pass123
The Reader application(The code above) Should ask the user to enter his existing username and password and should be like the one above(User1 = usrname & pass123 = password) The code above should also check if the user has entered that data and compare it with the data in the password.txt, and here comes my question: 
The code above should do the process I mentioned, but what it do is it is comparing the Whole input twice once with the usrname and once with password

Comment: So it is giving me True False at the first time and False True at the second time, Can you help me to make it test each one alone? I mean firstly to check the username and secondly the password

Comment: Pls provide an example of your `password.txt` file in your question because the way your code is written it is unclear whether your `User1 Pass123` is all on one line or not.

Comment: GetSet it probably doesn't matter; you could just split and assume every even index is the user and the odd is the associated password .. or even just read all the text and search for user\npassword - the delimitation is probably largely irrelevant

Comment: *you can run this code if you want and mock up the password.txt, and check it.* - nothing in the given code appears to write/create a password.txt file

Comment: @CaiusJard  Yeah OP mentioned in comments that file contained `User1 Pass123` but I assumed as much from the mentioned current output that they are on separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your password.txt file is like this (which appears to be the case):

password.txt

```
User1 
Pass123
User2
Pass456
```

etc.

The way your code is written, with that loop you have, if the user enters `User1` for the username and `Pass123` for the password, the output will be:

```
Your username is: User1
Your password is: Pass123
```

BUT if the same user enters `User1` and `Pass456` the output will be:

```
Your username is: User1
Your password is: Pass456
```

Which is obviously undesirable logic.

So what you need is to use your loop to check for the matching username, and *only* when that condition is met, check for the matching password.

Otherwise you even get results like this, if the user enters `Pass123` for the username and `Pass456` for the password:

```
Your username is: Pass123
Your password is: Pass456
```

This can happen because you are not associating the password with the username. To make them connected you would write the code like this, assuming that username and password are on separate lines:

SOLUTION:

```
while(line != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(userInput == line);
    Console.WriteLine(password == line);

    if (userInput == line)
    {
    
// ** CHANGES BEGIN 
    
        line = reader.ReadLine(); // get password on next line
        if (line == password)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Credentials are valid");
            
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Credentials are invalid");
            
        }
        break; // no need to continue this loop
    }
    else {

        // Important: skip past password line since the username didnt match
        
        line = reader.ReadLine(); 
    }

// ** CHANGES END
    
    line = reader.ReadLine(); // this is now reading the next username or EOF
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that. Now I understand how to do it and why I should do it so, and how I should the next time think about it. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into your text file:

```
hello:world
```

Put the following into your code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filepath = @"C:\myProgramingFiles\password.txt";

        Console.WriteLine("Write your username:");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Write your password:");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

        var usrpwd = username + ":" + password;

        foreach(line in lines)
        {
            if(usrpwd == line)
                Console.WriteLine("Credentials accepted");
        }
    }
```

Run the app and type `hello` as the username and `world` as the password. Build from there ..

When it comes to saving new data in your text file look at [File.AppendAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=net-6.0) or read all your lines in, add new data in memory and then overwrite the whole file. That's probably most easily arranged by having the data in a list, rather than an array:

```
var lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(...));
```

Then you can `lines.Add(...)` a `user:password` pair and write it out again

Comment: Thank you! I am just learning further from you. :)